# How to make Gorhom sheet return to default value on flicks?

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet

I use `@gorhom/bottom-sheet` in my react-native project. I use `[0, 1, 2]` snap points, default being `1`.

When I expand the sheet to `2` and then do a gentle flick down, I get all the way down to `0`. I want gentle flick to mean just return to default `1`, and to only go down to `0` if the user drags the sheet all the way.

How could I achieve that?